Conditional growth of tcolorbox based on inner/outer pages
In the tcolorbox box size control, is it possible to enter values in the direction of right margin only if the page is an odd-numbered outer page, and in the direction of the left margin if the document is an inner (even-numbered) page? I ask because a box that is breakable needs that, but if I replace left and right by inner and outer in tcolorbox grow to left/right by=...cm options, it is not recognized and I don't know the syntax to achieve this conditional logic in tcolorbox.
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,colframe=blue,
    grow to left by=2cm,%   equivalent to negative mdframed 'leftmargin'
    grow to right by=-2cm,%  equivalent to negative mdframed 'rightmargin'
    enlarge top by=1cm,%     equivalent to mdframed 'skipabove'
    enlarge bottom by=1cm,%  equivalent to mdframed 'skipbelow'
    show bounding box,% display the bounding box
    overlay app={% draw the green arrow lines 
        \begin{scope}[very thick,<->,green!50!black]
            \draw (frame.west) -- node[above] {2cm} ++(-2cm,0);
            \draw (frame.east) -- node[above] {2cm} ++(2cm,0);
            \draw (frame.north) -- node[right] {1cm} ++(0,1cm);
            \draw (frame.south) -- node[right] {1cm} ++(0,-1cm);
    \end{scope}}]
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \lipsum[3]
    
    \lipsum[5]
    
    \lipsum[10]
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}


You could use the toggle enlargement option:
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,colframe=blue,
    toggle enlargement,
    grow to left by=2cm,%   equivalent to negative mdframed 'leftmargin'
    grow to right by=-2cm,%  equivalent to negative mdframed 'rightmargin'
    enlarge top by=1cm,%     equivalent to mdframed 'skipabove'
    enlarge bottom by=1cm,%  equivalent to mdframed 'skipbelow'
    show bounding box,% display the bounding box
    overlay app={% draw the green arrow lines 
        \begin{scope}[very thick,<->,green!50!black]
            \draw (frame.west) -- node[above] {2cm} ++(-2cm,0);
            \draw (frame.east) -- node[above] {2cm} ++(2cm,0);
            \draw (frame.north) -- node[right] {1cm} ++(0,1cm);
            \draw (frame.south) -- node[right] {1cm} ++(0,-1cm);
    \end{scope}}
    ]
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \lipsum[3]
    
    \lipsum[5]
    
    \lipsum[10]
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}



